# Plugin licensing behind a load-balancer

Tags: plugins, server, licensing

Currently drafting upgrades to our current hosting setup to support more users. It's a relatively simple website that uses an LMS plugin to serve courses to users.

My question is, if i put a few servers (either physical or in Aws) behind a load balancer (again, either nginx with the physical server approach or an Aws load balancer), but the database and static content are on an SQL server and a shared drive, will I have to pay for licences for each load-balanced server? After getting in touch with the plugin support, they didn't quite understand me and said separate wordpress installs (ie. with their own dB) each require their own licence.

What I'm trying to understand, then, is will I only pay for one licence if I host one SQL server and 5 nodes? What about one SQL master and a RW replica?

Thanks all.

Comment: There’s no single answer. It depends _entirely_ on the developer’s policies. As far as I’m concerned what you’re describing is a single install and any reasonable developer would treat it as such, but really no one here can tell you what’s correct for any particular plugin.